# If $H$ is a hyperplane of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then show that $\mathbb{R}^n-H$ has two connected components.

Tags: vector-spaces, connectedness

> Suppose $H$ is a hyperplane of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $\mathbb{R}^n-H$ has two connected components $C_1$ and $C_2$ that are convex.

I have little to none idea on how to show the existence of $C_1$ and $C_2$. Any hint or help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $H=f^{-1}(0)$ for some linear functional $f$. Define $C_1=f^{-1}((-\infty,0))$ and $C_2=f^{-1}((0,+\infty))$, which are open and disjoint for being the pre-image of two disjoint open sets.

Comment: At least, this should be intuitively obvious for $n = 1, 2, 3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: first do the special case when $$H = \{ (c_1, ... , c_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n : c_n = 0\}$$

Let $H^+$ (resp. $H^-$) be the set of $(c_1, ... , c_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $c_n$ is positive (resp. negative).  When $n = 3$, $H$ is the $xy$-axis, and $H^+$ and $H^-$ are obviously open, connected sets whose disjoint union is $\mathbb{R}^3 - H$.  Hence they are the connected components.

Show that $H^+$ is connected by showing that for any $v, w \in H^+$, the line

$$[v,w] = \{ tv + (1-t)w : t \in [0,1] \}$$

is contained in $H^+$.  This shows that $H^+$ is convex, hence path connected, hence connected.

Comment: Can you please clarify one thing: you put $c_n=0$ in $H$, then you construct $H^-$ and $H^+$ based on the sign of $c_n$, so these two sets aren't constructed from $H$?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "constructed from $H$."

Comment: I mean how can we discuss the sign of $c_n$ if we suppose $c_n = 0$. And also, it seems you prove the properties of $H$ but not those of $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus H$

Comment: I am not saying that $H^+$ and $H^-$ are subsets of $H$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be characterized by
$$
\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:(x-p)\cdot\overset{\rightarrow}{n}=0\right\}
$$
where $p$ is a point in the hyperplane and $\overset{\rightarrow}{n}$ is the normal to the hyperplane.